# vuejs pass model from parent component to children component and allow mutation

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Currently I have a `vue-multiselect` component which requires a `v-model`.

I want to wrap this component so that I can build one single-select component and one multi-select component.

While working on the single select component I encountered the following warning

`[Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "model"`

They are right but in my case **I really need to change the value from the parent** (like I replace my single-select code with the `vue-multiselect` code) component and I also do not want this warning.

Here is the code for my component:

```
Vue.component('single-select', {
    props: {
        model: {
            required: true
        }
    }
    template: '<multiselect\n' +
    '    v-model="model"\n' +
    ...>\n' +
    ...
    '</multiselect>'
});
```

One solution would be to pass a function as a model parameter and return the field from the parent but I really hope for a better solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vue has a shortcut for 2 way binding called [.sync modifier](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#sync-Modifier).

How it works in your case:

add .sync when you pass `model` as prop

```
<single-select :model.sync="..."></single-select>
```

emit an `update:model` in the child's input event

```
Vue.component('single-select', {
    props: {
        model: {
            required: true
        }
    },
    template: `<multiselect :value="model" @input="$emit('update:model', $event)"> </multiselect>`
});
```

Comment: I modified my code as `<d2-multiselect :model.sync="form.widgetName" ...` and `<multiselect v-model="model" @input="$emit('update:model', $event)"` and I keep getting the same warning. Using vue debugger I saw the the event is emitted.

Comment: @tzortzik try chaging `v-model="model"` to `:value="model"` ?

Comment: Seems to work, the model is changing and the warning is not appearing anymore. Why?

Comment: @tzortzik from https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Basic-Usage `Although a bit magical, v-model is essentially syntax sugar for updating data on user input events, plus special care for some edge cases.` . `v-model="model"` is sort of equal to `:value="model" @input="model = $event.target.value"`, therefore the prop is mutated when v-model is used

Answer (score -1):

Just give the internal `model` reference a different name, and the in the Vue component's data function map it manually:

```
Vue.component('single-select', {
    props: {
        model: {
            required: true
        }
    },
    data: function() {
        return {
            singleSelectModel: this.model
        };
    }
    template: '<multiselect v-model="singleSelectModel"></multiselect>';
});
```

This is of course, assuming that you **do not want to mutate the parent data**, but simply making a copy of `model` and giving the child component the freedom to change it whenever it wants.

If what you want is to also update the parent data from the child, you will have to look into emitting events from the child and listening in the parent.